# Problem in Application_Error in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net

my problem is User.Identity.Name or Request.Url.AbsoluteUri in exception handling is empty when exception email to me.

this is Application_Code:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Server.Transfer("~/errors/default.aspx");
}
```

and this is default.aspx code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Server.GetLastError() == null)
        return;
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    if (ex == null)
        return;

    string message = string.Format("User: ", User.Identity.Name);
    message += Environment.NewLine;
    message += string.Format("AbsoluteUri: ", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    message += Environment.NewLine;
    message += string.Format("Form: ", Request.Form.ToString());
    message += Environment.NewLine;
    message += string.Format("QueryString: ", Request.QueryString.ToString());
    message += Environment.NewLine;
```

but i receive email like this (this is header without full exception content):

```
User: 
AbsoluteUri: 
Form: 
QueryString: 
Browser Capabilities:
Type = IE8
Name = IE
Version = 8.0
Platform = WinXP
Is Crawler = False
Supports Cookies = True
Supports JavaScript = 1.2
```

why username and request url is emty?

this problem is exist when i replace transfer with redirect or i don't use both.

tanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You do not have set the string.Format in the correct way**

Try this.

```
string.Format("AbsoluteUri: {0}", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

How ever I suggest to use StringBuilder for this code.

Comment: good call on the stringbuilder too, the AppendFormat method would be ideal